# How to avoid #error directive compiling HCL Notes program in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, hcl-notes

This is probably a stupid question but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to compile a program for HCL Notes (formerly Lotus/IBM Notes). I'm using Visual Studio 2022 C++, running under Windows 11, target is Release x64 for Windows. Getting the compile error:

```
#error directive: Must specify type of OS ("DOS", "OS2", etc) on C command line!
```

This is coming from the HCL header "global.h" which is trying to make me include some kind of switch to specify the operating system target. I've tried about everything I can think of on the "additional options" compiler command line, but I still get the error. Below is the relevant portion of the header file.  Any insight on this would be appreciated.

```
#if defined(OS400)  /* This should appear before the OS2 test below, because that section tests for __IBMCPP__,
                            which our C++ compiler also generates */
    #define PLATFORM_NAME "OS/400"
    #ifndef UNIX
        #define UNIX
    #endif
    #ifndef W32
        #define W32             /* Compile for Windows 32 API - its emulated */
    #endif
    #ifndef W
        #define W               /* Compile for Windows 32 API - its emulated */
    #endif
    #if !defined(MIRAGE) && !defined(INTERNOTES)
        #define MIRAGE
    #endif
    #ifndef HANDLE_IS_32BITS
        #define HANDLE_IS_32BITS
    #endif
    #define BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER
    #define PREEMPTIVE
    #define SEMAPHORES
    #define SEMALLOC
    #define ODS_NEEDED TRUE
    #define COMPILER_INT_SIZE 4
    #define REQUIRED_ALIGNMENT 16
    #define NATURAL_ALIGNMENT 16
    #define PTRISNOT32BIT
    #define COMPILER_DWORD_ALIGNMENT 4
    #define COMPILER_NUMBER_ALIGNMENT 8
    #define VIM_USE_UNIX
    #define THREADS
    #ifndef NOGUI
        #define NOGUI
    #endif
    #if defined(__ILEC400__) || defined(__AIXxiCC__) || defined(__AIXxxlC400__)
        #define ILEC400
    #endif
#elif defined(NT) || (defined(W32) && !defined(UNIX))
    #ifndef W32
        #define W32
    #endif
    #ifndef W
        #define W
    #endif
    #ifndef NT
        #define NT
    #endif
#ifdef W64
    #define PLATFORM_NAME "Windows/64"
#else
    #define PLATFORM_NAME "Windows/32"
#endif
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
        #define MSC
    #endif
    #if defined(__IBMC__) || defined(__IBMCPP__)
        #define IBM_C
    #endif
    #define THREADS
    #define LITTLE_ENDIAN_ORDER
    #define PREEMPTIVE
    #define SEMAPHORES
    #define SEMALLOC
    #ifdef _X86_
        #define ODS_NEEDED FALSE
        /* Suppress "used #pragma pack to change alignment" */
        #pragma warning(disable:4103)
        /* Note: If you change the packing, you must also change inc\globpack.h */
        #pragma pack(1)
        #define REQUIRED_ALIGNMENT 1
        #define COMPILER_DWORD_ALIGNMENT 1
        #define COMPILER_NUMBER_ALIGNMENT 1
    #else
        #define ODS_NEEDED TRUE
        #define COMPILER_DWORD_ALIGNMENT 4
        #ifdef W64
            /* suppress "conversion from '' to '', possible loss of data warning */
            #pragma warning(disable: 4267)  
            /* suppress "conversion from '' to '', of greater size warning */
            #pragma warning(disable: 4306)  
            #define PTRISNOT32BIT
            #define PTRIS64BIT
            #define REQUIRED_ALIGNMENT 8
            #define NATURAL_ALIGNMENT 8
            #define COMPILER_NUMBER_ALIGNMENT 8
        #else
            #define REQUIRED_ALIGNMENT 4
            #define NATURAL_ALIGNMENT 4
            #define COMPILER_NUMBER_ALIGNMENT 4
        #endif
        #ifndef HANDLE_IS_32BITS
            #define HANDLE_IS_32BITS
        #endif
    #endif
    /* suppress "access-declarations are deprecated; member using-declarations provide a better alternative" warnings */
    #pragma warning(disable: 4516)
    #if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
        /* suppress "name was marked as #pragma depracted - _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS should have covered this but some it did not */
        #pragma warning(disable: 4995)
        #pragma warning(disable: 4996)

        /* No checking on iterators in the product */
        #define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 0
    #endif

    #define COMPILER_INT_SIZE 4
    #define VIM_USE_MSWIN_NT
    #define OLEW32
    /*  Enable some OLE definitions which are only available for NT 4.0 and
        above.  The programmer must be careful not to use them on other
        Win32 platforms.
    */
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
    /* Keep this in sync with what is in w32prags.h and w64prags.h */
    #if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
        #define _WIN32_WINNT    0x0501  /* Changed to 0501 so now at XP level */
    #else
        #define _WIN32_WINNT    0x0400
    #endif
#endif
#elif defined(MAC)
    #ifndef THREADID_IS_64BITS
    #define THREADID_IS_64BITS
    #endif

    #if defined(__powerc) || defined(powerc) || defined(__ppc__)
        #ifndef MAC_POWERPC
        #define MAC_POWERPC
        #endif
    #elif defined(__i386__) || defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__arm__) || defined(__arm64__)
        #ifndef MAC_X86
        #define MAC_X86
        #endif
    #else
        #error Undefined Mac processor
    #endif
    #if defined(IOS)
        #define PLATFORM_NAME "iOS"
    #else
        #if defined(ND64)
            #define PLATFORM_NAME "Macintosh/64"
        #else
            #define PLATFORM_NAME "Macintosh"
        #endif
    #endif
    #if defined(__BIG_ENDIAN__)
        #define BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER
    #else
        #define LITTLE_ENDIAN_ORDER
    #endif
    #ifndef HANDLE_IS_32BITS
        #define HANDLE_IS_32BITS
    #endif
    #if defined(ND64)
        #define PTRIS64BIT
        #define PTRISNOT32BIT
        #ifndef LONGIS64BIT
            #define LONGIS64BIT
        #endif
        /* We need this alignment for 64bit pointers */
        #define NATURAL_ALIGNMENT 8
        #define MEMALLOC_ALIGNMENT 8
    #endif
    #define THREADS
    #define PREEMPTIVE
    #define SEMAPHORES
    #define SEMALLOC
    #define ODS_NEEDED TRUE
    #define COMPILER_INT_SIZE 4
    /* For now, use 68k alignment for all Mac platforms */
    #if defined(ND64)
        #define REQUIRED_ALIGNMENT 8
        #define COMPILER_DWORD_ALIGNMENT 4
        #define COMPILER_NUMBER_ALIGNMENT 8
    #elif defined(MAC_X86)
        /* Try native alignment for Intel because ODS does not support 68k alignment with little endian */
        #define REQUIRED_ALIGNMENT 4        /* Intel supports odd-byte addressing, but it can't be used with system headers */
        #define COMPILER_DWORD_ALIGNMENT 4  /* Compiler will pad DWORDs to DWORD boundary if possible */
        #define COMPILER_NUMBER_ALIGNMENT 4
    #elif defined(MAC_POWERPC)
        #define REQUIRED_ALIGNMENT 1        /* PowerPC supports odd-byte addressing if truly required */
        #define COMPILER_DWORD_ALIGNMENT 2  /* Compiler will pad DWORDs to DWORD boundary if possible */
        #define COMPILER_NUMBER_ALIGNMENT 2
    #else
        #define REQUIRED_ALIGNMENT 1        /* 68020 or later CPUs only (not 68000) */
        #define COMPILER_DWORD_ALIGNMENT 2  /* Compiler will pad DWORDs to WORD boundary, because any further alignment is unnecessary */
        #define COMPILER_NUMBER_ALIGNMENT 2
    #endif
    #define VIM_USE_MAC
    /* Tdanalzye is a rudimentary parser, that is failing to correctly parse this long #if #elif statements.
     * It is re-processing the UNIX section after it has already processed the OS400 section and incorrectly
     * using a COMPILER_NUMBER_ALIGNMENT of 4.  So for now, add a redundant !OS400, until tdanalzye is fixed.
     */
#elif defined(UNIX)  && !defined(OS400)
    #ifndef W32
        #define W32             /* Compile for Windows 32 API - its emulated */
    #endif
    #ifndef W
        #define W               /* Compile for Windows 16 API - its emulated */
    #endif
    #if !defined(MIRAGE) && !defined(INTERNOTES)
        #define MIRAGE
    #endif

    #if (defined(ODT) || defined(SOLX86) || defined(UNIXWARE) || defined(OSF) || defined(LINUX)) && !defined(ZLINUX)
        #define LITTLE_ENDIAN_ORDER
    #else
        #define BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER
    #endif
    #define PREEMPTIVE
    #define SEMAPHORES
    #define SEMALLOC
    /* All 32-Bit UNIX type platforms except Solaris,HPUX, and AIX are 32 bit handle platforms */
    /* All 64-Bit UNIX type platforms are presently 32bit handles, but may be 64bit handles */
    /* This needs to be here so that it is also included in the SDK */
    #if defined(OSF) || defined(AIX64) || defined(SOLARIS64) || defined (LINUX64) || defined(__64BIT__) || defined(NDUNIX64)

        #ifdef ENABLE_64HANDLE
            #ifndef HANDLE_IS_64BITS
                #define HANDLE_IS_64BITS
            #endif
        #else
            #ifndef HANDLE_IS_32BITS
                #define HANDLE_IS_32BITS
            #endif
        #endif
        #define PTRIS64BIT
        #ifndef LONGIS64BIT
            #define LONGIS64BIT
        #endif
        #if defined(LINUX64) && !defined(THREADID_IS_64BITS)
            #define THREADID_IS_64BITS
        #endif
        #define PTRISNOT32BIT
        /* We need this alignment for 64bit pointers */
        #define NATURAL_ALIGNMENT 8
        #define MEMALLOC_ALIGNMENT 8
    #else
        #if !(defined(SOLARIS) || defined(HPUX) || defined(SOLX86) || defined(AIX))
            #ifndef HANDLE_IS_32BITS
            #define HANDLE_IS_32BITS
            #endif
        #endif
    #endif

    #if defined(AIX)
        #if defined(ND64)
            #define PLATFORM_NAME "AIX/64"
        #else
            #define PLATFORM_NAME "UNIX"
        #endif
        #define XLC_C
    #elif defined(SUN) || defined(SOLARIS)
        #if defined(ND64)
            #define PLATFORM_NAME "Solaris/64"
        #else
            #define PLATFORM_NAME "UNIX"
        #endif
        #define SUN_C
    #elif defined(HPUX)
        #define PLATFORM_NAME "UNIX"
        #define HP_C
    #elif defined(OS390)
        #define PLATFORM_NAME "UNIX"
        #define OS390_C
    #elif defined(UNIXWARE)
        #define PLATFORM_NAME "UNIX"
        #define UW_C
    #elif defined(__osf__)
        #define PLATFORM_NAME "UNIX"
        #if !defined(OSF)
            #define OSF
        #endif
        #define DEC_C
    #elif defined(ANDROID)
        #define PLATFORM_NAME "Android"
    #elif defined(EMSDK)
        #define PLATFORM_NAME "WebBrowser"
    #elif defined(LINUX)
        #if defined(ND64)
            #define PLATFORM_NAME "Linux/64"
        #else
            #define PLATFORM_NAME "UNIX"
        #endif
        #define GCC
    #else
        #define PLATFORM_NAME "UNIX"
    #endif

    #if (defined(SOLARIS) || defined(AIX) || defined (HPUX) || defined(OS390) || defined(LINUX)) && !defined(DISABLE_THREADS)
        #define THREADS
    #endif
    /*  ODS needed, even for ODT (on x86 machines), because X includes
        don't support having the compiler set for tight packing (-Zp1),
        that is, they assume padding.  With padding enabled, we must use
        ODS even when theoretically unncessary.  Perhaps the X headers
        can be kludged to explicitly pad so that this is unnecessary. */
    #if defined(ODT_LATER)
        #define COMPILER_INT_SIZE 4
        #define REQUIRED_ALIGNMENT 1
        #define COMPILER_DWORD_ALIGNMENT 2
        #define COMPILER_NUMBER_ALIGNMENT 2
    #else
        #define ODS_NEEDED TRUE
        #define COMPILER_INT_SIZE 4
        #if defined(ND64) 
            #define REQUIRED_ALIGNMENT 8
        #else
            #define REQUIRED_ALIGNMENT 4
        #endif
        #define COMPILER_DWORD_ALIGNMENT 4
        #if defined(SOLARIS) || defined(HPUX) || defined(OS390) || defined(ZLINUX) || (defined(LINUX86) && defined(LINUX64)) || defined(ANDROID64) || defined(EMSDK)
            #define COMPILER_NUMBER_ALIGNMENT 8
        #else
            #define COMPILER_NUMBER_ALIGNMENT 4
        #endif
    #endif
    #define VIM_USE_UNIX

#else
    #error Must specify type of OS ("DOS", "OS2", etc) on C command line!
#endif
```

Comment: You probably want to specify `W32` and `W64` macros. In the Visual Studio IDE, that would be `C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions`

Comment: Yeah I had tried that before, it doesn't seem to work.  This is what I have for Preprocessor Definitions: WIN32;NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;W32;W64;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)

Comment: I switched back to the Notes 9 version of global.h and got rid of the error, not sure why that happened.  Unfortunately my crash continues, I believe because I'm not compiling correctly for 64 bit, but that is a separate issue.